# Error: Error creating CloudTrail: InvalidCloudWatchLogsLogGroupArnException

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create cloudtrail for an organization in AWS. When I try to run the plan on a targeted apply for

```
resource "aws_cloudtrail" "nfcisbenchmark" {
  name                          = "nf-cisbenchmark-${terraform.workspace}"
  s3_bucket_name                = aws_s3_bucket.nfcisbenchmark_cloudtrail.id
  enable_logging                = var.enable_logging
  # 3.2 Ensure CloudTrail log file validation is enabled (Automated)
  enable_log_file_validation    = var.enable_log_file_validation
  # 3.1 Ensure CloudTrail is enabled in all regions (Automated)
  is_multi_region_trail         = var.is_multi_region_trail
  include_global_service_events = var.include_global_service_events
  is_organization_trail         = "${local.environments[terraform.workspace] == "origin"? true : var.is_organization_trail}"
  # 3.7 Ensure CloudTrail logs are encrypted at rest using KMS CMKs (Automated)
  kms_key_id                    = aws_kms_key.nfcisbenchmark.arn
  depends_on                    = [aws_s3_bucket.nfcisbenchmark_cloudtrail]
  cloud_watch_logs_role_arn     = aws_iam_role.cloudwatch.arn
  cloud_watch_logs_group_arn    = "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.nfcisbenchmark.arn}:*"

  event_selector {
    # 3.11 Ensure that Object-level logging for read events is enabled for S3 bucket (Automated)
    read_write_type           = "All"
    include_management_events = true
  }


}
```

I get `Error: Error creating CloudTrail: InvalidCloudWatchLogsLogGroupArnException: Access denied. Check the permissions for your role.` Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of the AWS provider are you using? Can you also share the code that creates the `aws_iam_role.cloudwatch.arn` and `aws_cloudwatch_log_group.nfcisbenchmark.arn` resources please?

Comment: The version that I am using is ~> 2.6.

Answer (score 2):

[Version 3.0.0 of the AWS provider](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/bc9ee2d8bd9548ea3f585799789b7f5cb537cd89/CHANGELOG.md#300-july-31-2020) bundled [a breaking change to the `aws_cloudwatch_log_group` resource's ARN output by stripping the `:*` suffix returned previously](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/14214). Instead you now have to explicitly add this in places where the AWS API wants the `:*` suffix. All of the documentation was then updated to follow this pattern as well which is why you see this in the [`aws_cloudtrail` resource documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudtrail):

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "example" {
  name = "Example"
}

resource "aws_cloudtrail" "example" {
  # ... other configuration ...

  cloud_watch_logs_group_arn = "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.example.arn}:*" # CloudTrail requires the Log Stream wildcard
}
```

For you though, on v2.6.0, your ARN already includes this `:*` so you don't need to add it an extra time but you do need to remember to strip the `:*` suffix on resources where the AWS API doesn't want that suffix (by the looks of [this issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/13046) then the [`aws_datasync_task` resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/datasync_task) is one of those).

Alternatively you could update your AWS provider to > v3.0.0 and keep the suffix there which will help you with a lot of other potential issues in the future.

Comment: my resource has the ':*' suffix attached to it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Read the answer again. On v2.6.0 like you have you need to drop the `:*` suffix. You only need to add that `:*` suffix to `aws_cloudwatch_log_group.example.arn` when you are on v3.0.0 or higher.